# How verify json input with yaml schema in Android

Tags: java, android, json, yaml

I have a Yaml schema that is used to describe valid JSON files (3rd party developed).

Now I get JSON input from 3rd party source and I would like to validate against that .yaml schema file to see if the JSON input conforms to the yaml schema describing the JSON file structure.

How would I do that? What library can I use (gradle/maven) to verify a JSON file against a .yaml schema file?